# CVPixelFormatType: What do the pixel formats mean?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I am working with input and have come across an enumeration CVPixelFormatType.  What do the different pixel formats mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [CVPixelFormatDescription](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CVPixelFormatDescriptionRef/Reference/reference.html) in the Apple docs

Comment: Unfortunately, that page doesn't describe them, either. In fact it says you should use that class only if you want to define a custom format type. But the OP, and me, want to know what the existing format types mean. For example, what on earth does "6 bit one component IEEE half-precision float, 16-bit little-endian samples" mean?

Comment: @VaddadiKartick The OP accepted this answer **four years ago**, so it seems presumptuous for you to say that it doesn't answer his question.  If you're not satisfied, feel free to ask a new question with more precise details.

Comment: Just because the OP accepted it doesn't automatically make it a useful answer. There are no "precise details" to be asked in another question, because the problem is not with the question, but with the answer. Link-only answers are also not considered ideal on Stack Overflow. If you don't want to answer it, that's perfectly fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this who couldn't find the answer on the accepted answer's link, you have to scroll down a little, read a little, and click the link on that page which says, Pixel Format Identifiers.

Here's a direct link to those descriptions - [Pixel Format Identifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvpixelformatdescription/1563591-pixel_format_identifiers)

For more information about the format options, since they may be cryptic to some, perhaps it's worth noting:

- RGB represents the three color channels (Red, Green, Blue).
- RGBA represents the three color channels plus A (Alpha), which is used for transparency.
- The bit option (24-bit, 32-bit, 48-bit) divided by the number of channels (RGB (3) or RGBA (4)) tells you the number of bits allocated to each channel which tells you how many possible colors are available.

24-bit RGB means 8 bits per channel, or 255 possible options per channel. 255^3 = 16.5 million possible colors.

48-bit RGB means 16 bits per channel, or 32,368 possible options per channel. Which is 33.9 trillion possible colors.